# javascript FOR don't change class

Tags: javascript, class, for-loop, frontend

I'm trying to build a JavaScript function for this code, but when I click:

```
<input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('BusquedaPorFecha', 'ConsultasEmpleado');" value="Busqueda por Fecha" />
```

And before:

```
<input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('BusquedaPorDepartamento', 'ConsultasEmpleado');" value="Busqueda por Departamento" />
```

The first `div` does not change its class.

I think the problem is caused by the for loop.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function VerConsultas(id,exception) {
        var Consultas = document.getElementById(id);
        var visibles = document.getElementsByClassName("visible");
        var Excepcion = document.getElementById(exception);
        for (var i = 0; i < visibles.length; i++)
        {
            visibles[i].className = "hide";
        }
        if (Consultas.className == "visible") {
            Consultas.className = "hide";
        } else {
            Consultas.className = "visible";
        }
        if (Excepcion != null) { Excepcion.className = "visible";}
    }
</script>
```

**Html inputs**

```
<nav id="TopNavigator">
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('AltaEmpleado', '');" value="Alta Empleado" />
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('BajaEmpleado', '');" value="Baja Empleado" />
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('ModificarEmpleado', '');" value="Modificar Empleado" />
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('ConsultasEmpleado', '');" value="Consultas Empleado" />
</nav>
<nav id="ConsultasEmpleado" class="hide">
     <asp:Button ID="Todos" runat="server" Text="Mostrar Todos los empleados" OnClick="TodosEmpleados" /><br />
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('BusquedaPorFecha', 'ConsultasEmpleado');" value="Busqueda por Fecha" />
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('BusquedaPorCategoria', 'ConsultasEmpleado');" value="Busqueda por Categoria" />
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('BusquedaPorDepartamento', 'ConsultasEmpleado');" value="Busqueda por Departamento" />
     <input class="boton" type="button" onclick="VerConsultas('BusquedaPorSalario', 'ConsultasEmpleado');" value="Busqueda por Salario" />
</nav>
```

**Html Divs**

```
<div class="hide" id="BusquedaPorFecha">
     Insertar una fecha
</div>
<div class="hide" id="BusquedaPorCategoria">
     Seleccione una Categoría
</div>
<div class="hide" id="BusquedaPorDepartamento">
     Seleccione un Departamento
</div>
<div class="hide" id="BusquedaPorSalario">
     Inserte un salario desde el que iniciar la búsqueda
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LL3g02yu/1/)

Comment: So you show us function `divView` and on click you execute `VerConsultas`. You expect us to imagine `VerConsultas` code?

Comment: sorry, divView and VerConsultas is the same function

Comment: I'm trying to understand here, what do you want to achieve exactly? When the button gets clicked, what should happen, in general terms? Thanks. pd: I know spanish btw.

Comment: Can you please post a demo in jsfiddle or jsbin.com ??

Comment: @undefined intento que la función haga algo bastante simple en principio.
al pulsar un botón, debe ocultar(hide) todos los elementos visibles, para después mostrar(visible) los que se encuentran en los parametros, pero al pasar en el for el número de elementos por referencia, al poner uno visible en hide, el indice cambia y sale del bucle. La función actualmente solo me vale para una "capa" pero intento que sea para un número x de "capas"

Comment: Y la excepción? No la veo en tu código, así que no le veo mucho sentido.

Comment: La excepción se comportaría igual, pero es para indicar que id sería la excepción, he tratado de hacerlo con un split y le he metido jquery también... pongo un fiddle:
[link jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LL3g02yu/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which get's updated when the DOM changes, so when you apply the `.hide` class, the node gets removed from the collection.

You could just use `document.querySelector(".visible")` which returns a NodeList, but it's slower (although we are talking about milliseconds here).

You could also convert it into an array to prevent it from updating, like this:

```
var visible = document.getElementsByClassName("visible"); //collection
    visible = [].slice.call(visible); //array
```

A couple of other points, you shouldn't use inline javascript like that, It's better to keep your scripting files and your structure files sepparate.

To that end, I've made a fiddle with a couple modifications to your code, [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6p0cyfmo/).

### inputs

```
<input  type="button" class="filtro"
        data-consultas="BusquedaPorSalario" 
        data-exc="ConsultasEmpleado"
        value="Búsqueda Por Salario"/>

<input  type="button" class="filtro"
        data-consultas="BusquedaPorFecha" 
        data-exc="ConsultasEmpleado"
        value="Búsqueda Por Fecha"/>
```

**Note:** The `.filtro` class was added to reduce the reduce the amount of elements to search for.

**Note:** The `data-consultas` and `data-exc` values account for the `id,exception` parameters in your function. `data-*` attributes are a standart that allows as to create custom attributes.

### JavaScript

```
inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("filtro");
for( var i = 0 , l = inputs.length; i < l ; i ++ ){
    input = inputs[i];
    input.addEventListener("click",VerConsultas);
}

function VerConsultas(e){
    var data = e.target.dataset;
    var id = data.consultas;
    var exc = document.getElementById(data.exc);
    var consultas = document.getElementById(id);
    var visible = document.getElementsByClassName("visible");
    visible = [].slice.call(visible);
    for( var i = 0 ,l = visible.length ;i < l ;i ++ ){
        var current = visible[i];
        current.className = "hide";
    }
    consultas.className = "visible";
    if( exc != null )
        exc.className = "visible";
}
```

Hope it helps :)